# how to pass a user password ,stored in config file to passwd command

Tags: bash, passwd

I am trying to create linux users using a script . The username and corresponding password are stored in a config file.

config file is given below

```
username="user1"
password="passxxx"
```

using a shell script i am creating linux users with username and password provided in config file.

```
if [ -n "$username" ] then

  password="$line" 
  sudo adduser $username 
  sudo passwd $username
```

Here i have to give  the password in the config file. usually we have to type the required password  twice to update the password information . Is there any way to update the password without typing ( use the password provided in config file) .

Comment: Unrelated but check out [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: You should check out the `passwd` options `-e` (expire, requires the user to change the password on next login) and `-i` (inactive, locks the account if a user did not log in within X days), so you don't end up with a system with user accounts having default passwords. Bad idea, security-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [chpasswd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd) instead of [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd) to set passwords in batch mode.

Example:

```
sudo chpasswd <<<"$username:$password"
```

Or, it you're using other shell (not bash of version >=3.0):

```
echo "$username:$password" | sudo chpasswd
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman, oh, thanks! I was very inattentive while typing answer.

Comment: I tried your solution ,but it shows errors .i fixed it with                         "$username:$password" | sudo chpasswd  ,and it works fine

Comment: sorry the full fix is   echo "$username:$password" | sudo chpasswd

Comment: @Adhz, both should be ok (`echo 'STRING' | COMMAND` and `COMMAND <<<'STRING'` should be equivalent in modern bash). What errors did you get?

Comment: @Adhz, probably you're using not bash, but some other shell (e.g. dash). Or too old bash (before 3.0). I'll extend my answer.

Comment: You are right I was using /bin/sh . i changed to /bin/bash/ and your fix worked